# File output keeps overwriting?

Tags: java, file, io

I'm trying to make a loop get user-inputted information 3 times and save them to a file. How come the file is continuously being overwritten? I originally was instantiating the File class from within my saveInfo() function, however I thought moving and handling that within the constructor would help, yet it doesn't?

Note: This class is instantiated from a main class, then go() is called.

```
package informationcollection;

import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Formatter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.lang.Integer;

public class Getter {

    private String name;
    private int age;
    private File fp;


    public Getter () {
        name = "";
        fp = new File("programOutput.txt");
        System.out.println("The Getter class has been instanstiated!");
    }

    public void go() {
        getInfo();
        System.out.println("The information has been saved to a file!");
    }

    public void getInfo() {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        int i;

        for(i=0;i<3;i++) {
            System.out.println("What is your name?");
            System.out.printf(">>: ");
            name = keyboard.nextLine();

            System.out.println("How old are you?:");
            System.out.printf(">>: ");
            age = Integer.parseInt(keyboard.nextLine());
            System.out.printf("We will save that your name is %s, and you are %d years old!\n", name, age);
            saveInfo();
        }

    }

    public void saveInfo() {
        try {
            Formatter output = new Formatter(fp);
            output.format("%s is %d years old!\n", name, age);
            output.flush();
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            System.out.println("File doesn't exist.");
        }



    }



}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As per the [`Javadoc`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#Formatter-java.io.File-) states (bold text my own):

> The file to use as the destination of this formatter. **If the file
>   exists then it will be truncated to zero size**; otherwise, a new file
>   will be created. The output will be written to the file and is
>   buffered.

You could use something like so to avoid your text being truncated:

```
PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("programOutput.txt", true)));
```

Comment: hehe ;) another api-lover!

Comment: @fge: You mean the `nio` package?

Comment: Everything `java.nio.file`, yes; otherwise known as NIO2, but anyway, your `new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(...))` could, and in fact should, in 2015, be replaced with `Files.newBufferedWriter(...)`.

Answer (score 3):

The java api to the `Formatter` constructor you use says the following:

> file - The file to use as the destination of this formatter. If the file exists then it will be truncated to zero size; otherwise, a new file will be created.

So you're deleting all content that's in the file every time you call the `Formatter(File file)` constructor.

To solve this define the Formatter as class member:

```
private String name;
private int age;
private File fp;
private Formatter output;
```

assign it in the constructor:

```
public Getter () {
    try {
        name = "";
        fp = new File("programOutput.txt");
        output = new Formatter(fp);
        System.out.println("The Getter class has been instanstiated!");
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("File doesn't exist.");
    }
}
```

and then just use it in the `saveInfo()` method!

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `Formatter` default constructor, just use the constructor [Formatter(Appendable a)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#Formatter(java.lang.Appendable))

```
public Formatter(Appendable a)
```

That helps you to append.

or go for `FileWriter`

```
FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile() ,true);
```

> [Constructs a FileWriter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html#FileWriter%28java.io.File,%20boolean%29) object given a File object. If the second argument is true, then bytes will be written to the end of the file rather than the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

Check the JavaDoc of [java.util.Formatter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#Formatter-java.io.File-). It states the following:

> If the file exists then it will be truncated to zero size; otherwise, a new file will be created.

Since every time you try to save your information you instantiate a new `Formatter`, you always truncate your file to zero size. To prevent that from happening, simply define a new attribute for your class which contains said `Formatter` and create it only once.